# Regex to match one occurrence of a character without the duplicates

Tags: regex

I have a file that has lines starting with triple ticks "```" and single tick "`".

I want to match only the single tick ones. So the expression would show me "`single" and not "```triple"

````
```triple
`single
````

Comment: what language is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following regex pattern:

```
^`(?!`).*$
```

This would match only lines starting with a single backpack.  Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6SfmxM/1).